# A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified data could not be decrypted

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mandrill

Once I am using mandrill smtp server instead of *smtp.gmail.com*, system fails(randomly) to send some email at first attempt and success in second attempt. 
I have some similar post but non of those solve my issue.

Here is the exception track trace (copied from database log, excuse me on bad format of the trace)

> *System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified data could not be
>   decrypted --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken
>   message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
>   message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
>   message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
>   message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
>   message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
>   Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult) at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object
>   state) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result) at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.Flush() at
>   System.Net.Mail.ReadLinesCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn) at
>   System.Net.Mail.EHelloCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String domain)
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint
>   servicePoint) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at
>   Nop.Services.Messages.EmailSender.SendEmail(EmailAccount emailAccount,
>   String subject, String body, MailAddress from, MailAddress to,
>   IEnumerable`1 bcc, IEnumerable`1 cc, String attachmentFilePath, String
>   attachmentFileName) at
>   Nop.Services.Messages.EmailSender.SendEmail(EmailAccount emailAccount,
>   String subject, String body, String fromAddress, String fromName,
>   String toAddress, String toName, IEnumerable`1 bcc, IEnumerable`1 cc,
>   String attachmentFilePath, String attachmentFileName) at
>   Nop.Services.Messages.QueuedMessagesSendTask.Execute()*

Here is the code block that use to send email

```
 using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
  {

            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = emailAccount.UseDefaultCredentials;
            smtpClient.Host = emailAccount.Host;
            smtpClient.Port = emailAccount.Port;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = emailAccount.EnableSsl;
            if (emailAccount.UseDefaultCredentials)
                smtpClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            else
                smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailAccount.Username, emailAccount.Password);
            smtpClient.Send(message);
   }
```

Comment: Stolen from the internets: "This is what happens if the Private Key in the RSACryptoServiceProvider changes on disk. When the LSASS.EXE process tries to complete the HTTPS handshake (this is always out-of-process to your application), it finds that the private key is unable to decrypt the data sent by the client, which was encrypted using the original private key. Lesson learned: While it's called a KeyContainer, it can only hold ONE exchange key at a time. If you want multiple keys (e.g. for multiple certificates) you need multiple containers."

Comment: Is there work any around to fix the issue?

Comment: No idea.  No idea if that's your issue.  May be domain related as well.  Good luck!

Comment: have you found something on this?